# Is it possible to close a process without forcing, killing it?

Tags: c#

When I create a process, I can use CloseMainWindow to an application that sends a message to the main window. In this way, I guess that the close of the application it is doing in a safe way, I mean, let the application to do what it has to do when is closing.

The documentation for that is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?view=net-6.0.

Well, in my case, I would like to know if it is possible to close a process that is not started in my application, it is an external process, so I don't have the chance to use Process.CloseMainWindow().

I know that one option is searching the process and kill it, but in this way, it forces the close of the process, and it would be that the application finishes in an inconsistency state.

For example, when there are opened applications and I shutdown Windows, it asked if I want to close the applications or not. If I don't reply and I let to pass time, sometimes it finally can close the applications before shutting down. I guess that it closes the applications in a good way because I can't imagine it will force to close the application without knowing the effects that it could be, but it is a guess, I am not sure about this.

In summary, is there any way to close a process in a safe way from a .NET application that is not opened but the application?

Thanks.

Comment: if or of not the process was started by you has no effect on `CloseMainWindow`, you canj use it even if didn't open the process yourself. The same applies to kill, doesn't it? So from your perspective you can use `CloseMainWindow` exactly the same way you'd use `Kill`.

Comment: Send a `WM_ENDSESSION` message with `TRUE` and `ENDSESSION_CLOSEAPP`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-endsession