# How close a process that don't have a user interface?

Tags: c#

I would like to close a process that has not user interface.

NOTE: This question has relation with [Is it possible to close a process without forcing, killing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73568541/is-it-possible-to-close-a-process-without-forcing-killing-it), but it is different because in the other question I wanted to know if it is possible to close an application that is not opened by the application. Here I want to know how to finish an application without UI.

In the documentation, I see that it uses this code:

```
// Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
// Free resources associated with process.
myProcess.Close();
```

The documentation is this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?view=net-6.0.

and this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.close?view=net-6.0.

It seems that first it close the window and later ensure to free all the resources that were used by the application.

it is said that this work if the application has user interface. But what happens when the application doesn't have a user interface?

In the documentation it is not said if close(), to free the resources, it is in a safe way or not. I have doubt because it is called after close the main window.

I was thinking too in first close the process to free the resources, but this doesn't close the process, it leave it still opened. At least if the application has user interface, if I only call the close() method, the windows is still visible.

So in summary, I would like to know which is the way to can close a process  that has not user interface.

Thanks.

Comment: Having a UI or not doesn't matter, all you need is to get the expected process(es) by Id, name, whatever and kill it/them. This topic is already largely covered all around Internet

Comment: A process can still have a main window, but just not make it visible.  So be sure to actually try what the documentation recommends.  Double-check with the Spy++ utility.

Answer (score 0):

In a UI application the framework contains a *message pump*, i.e. a loop that receives messages from windows regarding the UI, and process these according to some rules. Closing an UI application means stopping this loop and exiting the UI thread, and usually also the entire process. `.CloseMainWindow()` just sends a message asking the application to close, the application is free to ignore this message if it so chose.

A regular console program can closed by letting the main-method return. Trying to use `.CloseMainWindow()` will not do anything, since there is no message pump to receive any messages.

Note that you can always kill a process, and this will allow the OS to free all the memory, file handles, and other resources held by the process. But this may cause problems if the process is doing anything, like saving things to a file. So you should typically ask UI programs to exit nicely, so the user has a chance to save what he/she is doing.

Console programs are typically used for temporary work, that ideally does any writing to the console window or a new files, so there is usually less concern about data corruption since any broken files can just be deleted or overwritten.

Server programs usually run as a *service*, where the service also have mechanisms to send messages to the program and asking it to save any pending work and exit. See [How to stop Windows service programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317378/how-to-stop-windows-service-programmatically) for more details.

In the end it really depends on what you are doing and what degree of reliability your program is designed for. Ideally all programs should be designed so that they can be safely killed at any point without significant data loss, since this will sometimes happen for uncontrollable reasons, like power loss.